# Split lines and sequentially number each fragment in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, splitting, numbering

I have a line layer representing watermains that I need to split long lines into sections.  Each line has a unique ID number, but upon splitting a line this attribute is no longer unique as the fragments each have the same attribute.  I would like to be able to number each of the unique fragments sequentially so that we can identify them as originally belonging to a larger parent, but still be unique.  Upon splitting, each line breaks into different number of smaller sections.

For example

- Line 1 becomes lines 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
- Line 2 becomes lines 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.....2.47
- etc

I can see how to number the whole of the data set, but not number individual subsets.  Having the number as a new attribute would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @TomBrennan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373459/split-lines-and-sequentially-number-each-fragment-in-qgis#comment610139_373459), you could:

> ... just number them: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.4, 2.5, ..., 2.50 etc ... That
> would still meet the criteria of "originally belonging to a larger
> parent, but still be unique". The second ID could easily be added
> since you can number the whole dataset (so you have LineID - not
> unique - and SectionID - which is unique)